# Javascript form to open customize window

Tags: javascript

Create a Web page named lab17.html.

I'm very new in JS. I need to create a page with a form to allow the user to open a customized window as follows:

```
Enter a URL
Check Toolbar
Check Location
Check Directories
Check Status
Check Menubar
Check Scrollbars
Check Resizable
Enter a width
Enter a height
```

When the user clicks on Submit, get the data and open a new window loading the URL with the selected features.

That's what I have for now, but need help in creating function to get it work.

```
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h2>"+"Please choose  features for your window:<br>"+"</h2>")
// display all the names
for (var i=0; i<document.
openwindow.length; i++)
{
document.write(document.openwindow.
elements[i].name , "<br>")
}
</script>
<FORM name="openwindow">
<p>
<INPUT TYPE="url" VALUE="" NAME=""><br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="toolbar"
value="toolbar">Toolbar<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="location"
value="location">Location<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="directories"
value="directories">Directories<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="status"
value="status">Status<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="menuebar"
value="menuebar">Menuebar<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="scrollbars"
value="scrollbars">Scrollbars<br>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="resizable"
value="resizable">Resizable<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Submit"
value="Submit" onClick="window.open('')">
<INPUT TYPE="Reset" NAME="Reset"
value="Reset">
</FORM>
```

Comment: Read about [functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) and [DOM](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html).

Comment: ideally there **shouldn't** be a new window but data should be fetched and showed using form input data on the same page or a popup div/iframe through `Asynchronous` call *AJAX*. This way by opening a new window you are killing the purpose of `JavaScript`.

Comment: @Sajjad: It looks like this is an exercise to take the value of the input elements and use them as configuration for the new window. I think your comment is rather confusing than helping in this context.